# Page Not Found when get /info from gradle-git-properties/micronaut-management

Tags: gradle, micronaut, gradle-git

Context: I downloaded an initialized project from https://micronaut.io/launch/ and I added both  gradle-git-properties plugin and micronaut-management dependency in order to expose git.properties as explained in [adding commit info guide](https://guides.micronaut.io/adding-commit-info/guide/index.html)

I checked my project buil/resources/main and I see this git.properties

```
git.branch=
git.build.host=SPANOT149
git.build.user.email=jimis.drpc@gmail.com
git.build.user.name=Jimis.drpc
git.build.version=0.1
git.closest.tag.commit.count=
git.closest.tag.name=
git.commit.id=
git.commit.id.abbrev=
git.commit.id.describe=
git.commit.message.full=
git.commit.message.short=
git.commit.time=
git.commit.user.email=
git.commit.user.name=
git.dirty=true
git.remote.origin.url=
git.tags=
git.total.commit.count=0
```

So I assume the plugin is working properly.

Nevertheless, when I get http://localhost:8080/info the result is

```
{"message":"Page Not Found","_links":{"self":{"href":"/info","templated":false}}}
```

The closest tutorial beyond the above official guidance I found is [this quick guide](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-micronaut-framework/)  using Micronaut version 1.0.3 and with few extra steps in Maven. Note I am using Micronaut 2.1.3 and Gradle and, the oficial guidance uses Gradle also and hasn't such few extra steps.

Here are my:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.4.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.4.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.4.10"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.1.0"
    id "io.micronaut.application" version '1.0.5'
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.2.2"
}

version "0.1"
group "com.mybank"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime "netty"
    testRuntime "junit5"
    processing {
        incremental true
        annotations "com.mybank.*"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-management")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

}

mainClassName = "com.mybank.ApplicationKt"
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('11')
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demo
endpoints:
  info:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

gradle.properties

```
micronautVersion=2.1.3
kotlinVersion=1.4.10
```

As a final goal I want to use micronaut-management to expose some built-in management and monitoring endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/jimcinfoendpoint.

I copied your build config into that project and the `/info` endpoint appears to work.